# Hibernate join Entities on a column of type varbinary?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have 2 tables which both have a column named `Token` of type `varbinary`. When I try to join these entities with the below code, I get the following Exception.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from
>   varbinary to BIGINT is unsupported.

Is this expected when joining on a `varbinary` column?

```
@Entity(name = "Token1")
@Table(name = "tblToken1")
public class Token1Entity {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Token", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)
    private Token2Entity token2Entity;

// ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Most RDBMS's don't support joining CLOBs/BLOBs/BINARY/large fields, etc., in fact many don't even allow you to select them as you would normal other columns

Since this exception is coming back from the database itself, you might turn on sql debugging and get the SQL statement dumped or write one by hand and run it interactively.  I'm betting it won't work.

If the value can really be used for join, then perhaps you have the wrong data type on one end or the other.  Otherwise, you'll need to potential come up with a derived key that adequately represents the varbinary and join on that.  Of course, it's always an issue keeping the two in synch, so not easy, probably not what you wanted to hear.